# Custom tab bar background image - in iOS 4.x

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have made a tab bar iOS project, when I received the request to change the tab bar's background image to a custom image. The project is developed for iOS 4.x, so the iOS5's
`[tabBar setTabBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"custom.jpg"]]` does not work. Can you suggest me some simple solutions (if there is any possibility, I would not like to change the entire project)?

**Edit:**
Only three lines of code can resolve all:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage.png"]];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to put an `UIView` with your background image exactly behind the `UITabBar`. Then lower the opacity of your tabbar to 0.5 so you can see the background-image coming through.

```
UIView *bckgrndView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tabbar.frame.coords.x, tabbar.frame.coords.y, tabbar.frame.size.width, tabbar.frame.size.height)];
[bckgrndView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"custom.jpg"]];
[tabbar.superView insertSubView:bckgrndView belowSubview:tabbar];
tabbar.alpha = 0.5;
[bckgrndView release];
```

Sorry if my code contains some errors. I tried doing this by heart... But you'll catch the drift.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9021698/701043). Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NGTabBarController](https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGTabBarController), an open source tab bar replacement with customizable background image.