# custom UITabBar selected tab image, iOS 5 and up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating a custom `UITabBarController` where I customise the `tabBar` this way:

```
self.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTabBarBeta.png"];
```

I then change the selector indicator this way:

```
self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTabBarSegmentSelected.png"];
```

But apparently it becomes a selected image for all 4 of my tabs, where I would like to have *each tab* its own `selectionIndicatorImage`.

Any ideas on how to implement this kind of thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should be the size of selection indicator image ?

Comment: @Jango You're asking me? It's a question long answered - in the end it doesn't matter, but I'd stick with some 80x80 px images

Comment: I have 4 buttons in the UI so I calculated as 320/4 = 80 which worked fine :) and double for @2x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this:

[Setting a background image for a tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909379/setting-a-background-image-for-a-tabbar/9021698#9021698)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Or try this Github project

https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController

Comment: I know this GitHub project, it's too complicated, and the first link you gave actually creates a row of `UIButtons` instead of `UITabBar`

Comment: You can try Ray Wenderlich turotial for the same. Its a step by step process for implementing the same.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show how to customise the `tabBar` elements one by one.