# iOS 5 custom tab bar image vertical alignment

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm getting some odd behaviour with my custom tab bar. The images seem to be aligned incorrectly. Here is a screenshot (I have removed my own tab bar background to highlight my problem):

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code I'm using to set the images for each state:

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavController, whatsOnNavController, mapNavController, infoNavController, nil];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

// For iOS 5 only - custom tabs
if ([self.tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedImageTintColor)]) 
{

    // Set the background images
    //[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_over.png"]];

    [homeNavController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_home_over"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_home"]];
    [whatsOnNavController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_whats_on_over"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_whats_on"]];
    [mapNavController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_map_over"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_map"]];
    [infoNavController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_info_over"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_info"]];

}
```

All of my replacement tab images are correctly sized (49 pixels high and 80 pixels wide for the non-retina versions).

What could be causing this odd behaviour?

## --- Update ---

Here is an updated screenshot with the background in place:

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you should always have text inside a tabitem. The space was created by blank text.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "you should always have text inside a tabitem"? From the screenshot above, it seems that you already had text in tabBarItem.title

Comment: That text was part of the image so I tried to make the title just an empty string.

Comment: If the text is drawn as part of your image and you don't want to have extra text on top of it, just set a string with a space inside: @" ", it will do the trick because it's not an empty string and it will not show.

Answer (score 66):

There is a property on UIBarItem (UIBarButton item inherits from this class) `imageInsets`.

To use full height images (49px) for `finishedSelectedImage` and `finishedUnselectedImage` you need to set these image insets:

`tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);`

Comment: This worked for me but only for the unselected images. The selected images have a black line at the top! Any idea anyone pls?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Though 5,0,-5,0 looked more center aligned.

Comment: Still I can tap on that extra space which is below the map image option shown in question and also on the space above the map option after setting image insets. Why so?

Comment: Your answer helped me, +1 bro.

Answer (score 25):

You can fix this in Storyboard now. Storyboard size inspector image inset adjustment
[image: Storyboard Size Inspector for Tab Bar Item]

Select the Tab Bar Item you want to adjust, open the Size Inspector, and adjust the Top and Bottom Image Insets. You need to adjust them the same amount or they will just squish/stretch your image (so +5 in Top, and -5 in Bottom)

Answer (score 3):

This may seem a bit hackish but I believe it's the only way you can achieve what you want: you just need to use tab bar finished images which have a transparent 11 pixels "top padding" (22 pixels for retina). Your images will then have to be 60px (120px) high.

My app made it to the App Store using this technique, so you should be safe to use it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's pretty clever - I will try this on my next app. The app I was talking about in my initial question is already live.

Comment: Just keep adding extra top transparent padding on your tabBar image and it should centre align.

Answer (score 2):

This API is really poorly documented.

Your `finishedSelectedImage` should be an icon ~30x30 px. This is just the icon part of the tab. If you create a `finishedSelectedImage` that's too tall, the system will not put it right at the bottom of the screen.

Conceptually, you start with a full-width, 49px high `backgroundImage` for the tabBar, add a single-tab-width, 49px high `selectionIndicatorImage` which functions as the background image for the selected tab, then add a two versions of each tab's icon ~30x30 px, `finishedUnselectedImage` and `finishedSelectedImage`.

Answer (score -1):

If you add the image as a subview instead with frames defined, can help you out.
 [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709802/custom-tab-bar-background-image-in-ios-4-x)

Try using slightly smaller images, tabbar repositions them slightly

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how that could help me - I'm just targeting iOS 5.x here.