# How to remove space below the UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have created a `tabBar` and set image in it, but it leaves too much space below the `tabBarItem`. How can I remove that?

This is my `tabBar` than displaying right now

[image]

And I want to display it like this

[image]

To display Tabbar

```
firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
forthVC = [[ForthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForthViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    NSArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstVC,secondVC,thirdVC,forthVC, nil];

    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabController setViewControllers:viewControllersArray animated:NO];


    [self.window addSubview:self.tabController.view];

    //self.tabController.selectedIndex = 1;

    self.tabController.delegate = self;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

For tabBar background image i have used this code

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarimg1.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

And for set the imge at item i have used this code

```
//used to set the tabBarItem images
        [self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab"]];
        //Set the badge on tabBarItem
        [self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:@"15"];
```

Comment: where is your tabbar? as you have written "This is my tabbar than displaying right now"

Comment: Is there some problem as i add my picture in question it display some other image like GTA vice city image....Strange....

Comment: Hey @Kane Don't show your tabbar......

Comment: @Will now its done check now still dont understand what the problem when i first time added this picture at the time my first image display some polytical person who giving speaach and second image display Vicecity instead of my image so i have to remove image and reinserted it..

Comment: @BhaveshNai check now...

Comment: still no able to load the before tabbar.

Comment: can u show your code ?

Comment: @JayGajjar Which code tabBar?

Comment: @Will can you see now....

Comment: @Will Refresh your page its displaying to me.....

Comment: add some code how you have designed your tabbar?

Comment: @Will i have updated my answer check now...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Vytis says in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533917/ios-5-custom-tab-bar-image-vertical-alignment/12155249#12155249):

> There is a property on UIBarItem (UIBarButton item inherits from this
>   class) `imageInsets`.
>
> To use full height images (49px) for `finishedSelectedImage` and
>   `finishedUnselectedImage` you need to set these image insets:
>
> `tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);`

you have to write the following lines of code

> ```
> item0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
> item1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
> item2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
> item2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
> ```

Comment: When you copy the words of another, you need to explicitly call that out and link to the original answer. I've done so in the above, but please make sure you provide proper attribution in the future.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should use image insect in the xib for this like ,[image]

for your requirement top should be some positive value and bottom should be some same negative value . If you have added the tab bar programmatically then you can refer the Wills answer

Comment: I think this way its better b/c you can edit it on the interface builder, btw it still work on xcode 7