# How to add image to UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am using UITabBarController and want to add image to it, a whole image to tab bar, not to any tab item. Is it possible, can anyone guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: already solved check [this link][1]


  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709802/custom-tab-bar-background-image-in-ios-4-x

Comment: This is of tab bar i am asking for tab bar controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. May be it help

```
 UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"] 
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
// Set background for all UITabBars

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

// Set background for only this UITabBar

[[tabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `iOS 5` or greater you can use `setBackgroundImage`:

```
UITabBar *yourtabBar = [yourtabController tabBar];

[yourtabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.jpg"]];
```

Comment: question is about to add image to UITabBarController. I think you have to modify your ans. little bit.